# Equivalence between properties of compactness for metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I am attempting here to show the equivalence between the following three statements for the metric space $(X,d),$

> i) $(X,d)$ is compact, meaning every open cover admits a finite subcover
>   ii) $(X,d)$ is sequentially compact, meaning every sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence
>   iii) $(X,d)$ is complete and totally bounded

Many of these proofs already exist on StackExchange, but the posts I could find were scattered and incomplete.  This is an attempt to gather the proofs and to have someone $\underline{\text{check my reasoning and provide the remaining proofs I've been unable to do.}}$

If anyone knows shorter, more concise proofs, those would be appreciated! The post is already quite long as written.

**Notation**: $B_\rho(x)$ is an open ball of radius $\rho$ centered at $x,$ and $\mathbb{N}$ denotes the natural numbers.

---

i) $\implies$ ii): Let $\{p_i\}$ be an infinte sequence in $X.$  The set $S = \{p_1, p_2, \dots\}$ must have a cluster point, call it $p.$  If $S$ did not have a cluster point, then every open ball in $X$ would contain only a finite number of points.  Since $X$ is compact and every cover has a finite subcover, this would imply that $S$ is not infinite.  Since $S$ has a cluster point $p,$ pick $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p_{n_1} \in B_1(p).$  Then $n_2 > n_1$ such that $p_{n_2} \in B_{1/2}(p),$ and so on.  Then $p_{n_k}$ for $k = 1,2,\dots$ will be a subsequence that converges because the n-th term will be less than $1/n$ away from $p.$

ii) $\implies$ i) : Let $C = \{O_1, O_2 , \dots\}$ be a countable open cover of $X,$ and suppose that there is no finite subcover that covers $X.$  Let $x_1 \notin O_1$ but $x_1 \in X,$ $x_2 \notin O_1 \cup O_2$ but $x_2 \in X$ and so on.  One may always be able to pick such a point because no finite number of $O_i's$ cover $X.$  By hypothesis, the sequence $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ must have a convergent subsequence that converges to $x \in X.$  Since $x \in X,$ $x \in O_n$ for some $n.$  But this would mean that an infinte number of points must be in that $O_n,$ which is not allowed by the construction of the sequence $\{x_n\},$ thus a contradiction.

i) $\implies$ iii) : Let $C$ be the open cover $\{B_\epsilon(x)| x \in X\},$ where $\epsilon > 0.$  Since $X$ is compact, a finite number of $B_\epsilon$'s cover $X,$ hence there exists an $\epsilon$ net for $X,$ meaning its totally bounded. 
Directly showing i) implies iii) seems excessive because i) implies ii) which trivially implies iii).  I'd be interested to see a direct method if anyone knows one.

ii) $\implies$ iii) : Let $\epsilon > 0$ and assume that no finite collection of $B_\epsilon$ covers $X.$  Then for any finite collection of points in $X,$ namely $\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}$ there exists an $x \in X$ such that $d(x,x_i) > \epsilon$ for $i = 1, \dots, n.$  Let $y_n := x$ in this case.  Then it is clear that the sequence $\{y_n\}$ has no convergent subsequence because $d(y_n,y_m) > \epsilon$ for all $n,m$ not equal.  Completeness is trivially implied by ii), because if $X$ weren't complete, there would exist a Cauchy sequence in $X$ that didn't converge contradicting ii).

iii) $\implies$ ii) Letting $\{p_i\}$ be a sequence in $X,$ at least 1 $B_\epsilon$ contains an infinite number of points.  One may then construct a nested sequence of $\epsilon$-balls, each of which contain an infinite number of $p_i$'s. Using this nested sequence to create a subsequence of $p_i$'s, completeness implies that this subsequence will in fact converge in $X.$

iii) $\implies$ i) **Incomplete** - I've had some trouble showing this result directly without first using $iii) \implies ii) \implies i).$  I'd be interested to see how its done.

Comment: You can find a detailed proof in Royden & Fitzpatrick *Real Analysis*.

Comment: One may, for example, find the proof [here](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~seeger/522/c13.pdf)